# Windows Registry location for Google Chrome version

Tags: windows, google-chrome, registry, version

Where does Google Chrome store its version information locally?

I'm developing a Lua script to access application version information found in the Windows registry, but can't find a registry key associated with the current installed version of Google Chrome Browser.

The closest I've found was [this](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/a9bgVILbO7c), which indicates that the version info can be found at 
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome`.

However, on my system, there is no `Google Chrome` subkey under `Uninstall` in the `HKCU` hive or corresponding `HKEY_USERS` paths. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be that your installation of google chrome is somehow messed up. I do have this registry key and it contains two values with the current version number.

Another way although not through the registry would be to check the folders in Users/[username]/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/Application. I have a folder with the latest version number in there. (and a folder with an older version).

AND I found something in the registry which might also work on every client:
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID{5C65F4B0-3651-4514-B207-D10CB699B14B}\LocalServer32
The values there contain the version number in the path.

Comment: Great, this answers the question. I'll use either the registry key you listed or parse the path in "Program Files" to get the Chrome Version.

Answer (score 6):

The version can be found under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\BLBeacon`

Answer (score 5):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe\
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome\
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are logged in under admin user and when you setup google chrome you setup it under local machine you will find value in this path

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{9C447DD7-5DD2-358C-90A2-1997BD1D69D1}
```

maybe this name will be different {9C447DD7-5DD2-358C-90A2-1997BD1D69D1}

Answer (score -3):

Try uninstalling the python and reinstalling it. Worked for me !
also enable "App data" file as readable/writable in C:// as admin